# Regarding GooglePlaceApi in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios7, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Xcode7.2. I am facing a problem with Google Maps SDK for iOS.
I have read the documentation on developer.google.com.(iOS)

1. The first thing I did was installation of cocoa pods and setting up pod file, it generated workspace.
2. I was able to get the API key from the Google Developers Console

   If I use my API key in the URL in a web browser, it is displaying JSON format data:

   ```
    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=17.443619,78.441879&radius=500&type=atm&key=Myapi key...
   ```
3. But I am unable to get JSON data in the Xcode console. However, it is displaying nearby places (bars,atm,fuel,cafe etc) in my map view...

Could you help me out, so that I can parse json data?

```
 dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:googleRequestURlNew];
    
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(RetrievedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
```

If I keep breakpoint at this point, it is not executing I mean at dispatch_async. Even though the code is displaying nearby locations with respective of my latitude and longitude and given radius

Comment: Where does `kBgQueue` come from? Where did you place your code? Do you get to the `dispatch_async` call? Do you get to the `dataWithContentsOfURL:` call? I would recommend using `NSURLSession` instead, though.

Comment: No i am unable to get the data...i think dispatch _async method is not calling .....while creating google api key ..i have created it for browser key...i dnt created it for iOS key..

Comment: Please answer the questions asked.